# Grabbing audio from Chrome's x-webkit-speech Speech Recoginition

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit

The x-webkit-speech attribute in a text input field enables speech recognition in the Google Chrome browser.

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

The audio is sent to Google. Is there a way to take the audio that is recorded before it's sent to Google's servers and send it elsewhere? A way short of modifying the Chrome source that is.

Comment: this interests me. Also can we hit google's endpoint as a service for comparison purposes? I'd be interested in trying to beat the googs at speech recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can (easily) grab it. Security problems IMHO.

As an alternative you can use flash (the user MUST allow microphone recording)

Comment: I found this project: http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/   It'll have to do until something better opens up. I've also tried HTML5's getUserMedia but the audio recording aspect of that doesn't work yet.